# How to pass additional parameters to onChange function in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

So, I've faced this problem: I have this type of Element here, obviously there's event when changing the input, is it possible to pass params like this and access event as well? if so, how could I do it?

```
// this function accepts two other params index, stringValue
function onChange(index ,stringValue) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log("index?: " + index + " and value" + stringValue)
}

//this input is in Child Component
const index = 69;
const someRandomValue='iamstring';
<input defaultValue={name} onChange={onChange(index,iamstring)} />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **curried function** to implement that.

```
onChange = (index, stringValue) => (event) => {
...
}

...

<input defaultValue={name} onChange={this.onChange(index,iamstring)} />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the handler to a curried higher order function to return a function to be used as the callback that accepts the click event object

```
function onChange(index,stringValue) {
  return (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log("index?: " + index + " and value" + stringValue)
  };
}
```

Or you can proxy the event object through to the callback, remember to add the event object as an argument to the handler

```
function onChange(event, index ,stringValue) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log("index?: " + index + " and value" + stringValue)
}

<input defaultValue={name} onChange={e => onChange(e, index, iamstring)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can make onChange into a function that **returns** another function.

Then you can do something like this:

```
const Element = () => {
  const index = 69;
  const iamstring = 'iamstring';

  const onChange = (index, stringValue) => event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log('index?: ' + index + ' and value' + stringValue);
  };

  return <input defaultValue={name} onChange={onChange(index, iamstring)} />;
};
```

Bear in mind that the input's `onChange` prop expects a function, so you can only **execute** a function inside the `onChange` like this if that function is returning **another** function. (This is called a higher order function).